# the horizontal size of a border-bottom in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on styling HTML elements using CSS, and I need some help. I'm trying to create a bottom border for  elements that has a width of 20 pixels, not just a thickness of 20 pixels.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1eKj.png)

I attempted to style the  elements using CSS to create a bottom border with a width of 20 pixels. Here's the code I used:

```
h2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible as you specified, but the linked answer gives some information on how to achieve a similar result using a different approach.